# Filter and visible cells

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the VBA macro which I have made. It will filter on the names column and find the empty cells and from another sheet.

It is supposed to find the names of phone numbers and paste it there.

I want this for empty cells only but this code is working for every row.

How can I find the values for visible cells only?

```
Sub namenumbers()

    On Error Resume Next
    rw = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    MP = InputBox("Please enter Marketplace", "AU/AE/BR/CA/CN/DE/ES/FR/IT/UK/US/IN/JP/MX/SG/TR")
    Dim wb As Worksheet, rng As Range
    lrr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    r.AutoFilter
    BN = r.Find(what:="Numbers", after:=r(1)).Column
    Kolumn = r.Find(what:="names", after:=r(1)).Column
    r.AutoFilter Field:=Kolumn, Criteria1:="="

    Workbooks.Open "C:\Macros\names with numbers.xlsx"
    nw = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks(nw).Activate
    Workbooks(nw).Sheets(MP).Activate
    Workbooks(rw).Activate
    For I = 3 To lrr
        Cells(I, Kolumn) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(I, BN), Workbooks(nw).Sheets(MP).Range("B2:D1000000"), 3, 0)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean "empty cells" or "visible cells" ?

Comment: only for visible cells Like i am trying using this :"SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)" but not sure how to implement this

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Sub namenumbers()
    Dim wb As Workbook, MP, lrr As Long, wsData As Workbook, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, r As Range, BN As Long, Kolumn As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    MP = InputBox("Please enter Marketplace", _
                  "AU/AE/BR/CA/CN/DE/ES/FR/IT/UK/US/IN/JP/MX/SG/TR")

    Set r = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    lrr = r.Rows.Count

    BN = r.Rows(1).Find(what:="Numbers", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
    Kolumn = r.Rows(1).Find(what:="names", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

    Set wsData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Macros\names with numbers.xlsx").Worksheets(MP)

    For i = 3 To lrr
        With ws.Cells(i, Kolumn)
            If Len(.Value) = 0 Then
                .Value = Application.VLookup(ws.Cells(i, BN).Value, _
                                             wsData.Range("B2:D1000000"), 3, False)
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you so much for the support, But i want the macro to filter the column with empty column and then find the values only for the Empty cells only.